# Image is being stored correctly but can't display on Laravel Blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, image

The image is being correctly stored in the `storage/app/public/images` folder however when I try to display the image with the code below , it returns nothing. I will also attach my image Controller function

I have tried the following

```
<img src = "{{ asset('storage/app/public/images/artist.jpg') }}" />


<img class="rounded-circle" src="/storage/images/{{ $user->image }}" />
```

Controller function

```
 public function update_image(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();

    $imageName = $user->id.'_image'.time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $request->image->storeAs('images',$imageName);

    $user->image = $imageName;
    $user->save();

    return back()
        ->with('success','You have updated image.');

    }
```

Comment: Have you set up the storage symlink? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: yes @Alex , I have done this . It says when i try again that it exists already

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns nothing"?

Comment: @NicoHaase the image is not displaying , I mean.

Comment: Seems like everything is correct, you just have to link storage, using `php artisan storage:link` command

Answer (score 0):

That's cause you are storing the images in the storage folder and not in the public folder.

Run `php artisan storage:link`

and write in your code `<img src = "{{ asset($user->image) }}" />`

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk

Answer (score -1):

Your `asset()` helper should be point to the following:

```
asset('storage/images/artist.jpg');
```

This is because the new symlinked folder can be found at `public/storage` and the `asset()` helper creates links to the `public` folder. Removing `app/public` from the string should solve the problem.

Comment: I have done this, I tried again there now and it says it already exists

Comment: Sorry, going to write another answer

Comment: @John Updated this one

Comment: still not appearing

Comment: Can you confirm the full url of the image

Comment: @John What is the url of your local application?

Comment: The problem may be that the url does not have a location to your application, so the url can not be resolved.

Comment: no it is stored within my project file , I just removed the file locaiton after users

Comment: oh i see, can you show the url with your project file like `***/***`

Comment: C:\Users\*** ***\  storage\app\public\images\artist.jpg some reason i cant do the / but get the idea